# Finding next AI move using MinMax algorithm for Checkers

Tags: unity, algorithm, ai, board-game

I am currently working on a Checkers game using Unity ( human vs computer ) I am done with the base architecture of the game ie defining the rules, moves, jumps etc.

I am currently stuck in implementation of MinMax for computer AI. I know how it works but I am confused on two things. Firstly, the heuristics ( I am using simple red checker count - black checker count ) but I am not sure if its correct. Secondly, outputting the final path of nodes for my AI to make its next turn.

Below is my MinMax implementation so far.

```
int MiniMax(TreeNode node)
    {
        int depth = 2;
        List<TreeNode> pathNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        int final = MaxMove(node, depth, pathNodes);
        return final;
    }

int MaxMove(TreeNode currNode, int depth, List<TreeNode> pathNodes)
{
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return currNode.getPriority();
    }
    else
    {
        depth--;
        int v = -10000;
        List<TreeNode> allPossRedMoveNodes = gameBoardScript.createNewRedBoardsFromCurrent(currNode.getCurrentBoard());
        foreach (TreeNode RedNode in allPossRedMoveNodes)
        {
            int v1 = MinMove(RedNode, depth,pathNodes);
            if(v1 > v)
            {                 
                v = v1;
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

int MinMove(TreeNode currNode, int depth, List<TreeNode> pathNodes)
{
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return currNode.getPriority();
    }
    else
    {
        depth--;
        int v = 10000;
        List<TreeNode> allPossBlackMoveNodes = gameBoardScript.createNewBlackBoardsFromCurrent(currNode.getCurrentBoard()); 

        foreach (TreeNode BlackNode in allPossBlackMoveNodes)
        {
            int v1 = MaxMove(BlackNode, depth,pathNodes);
            if (v1 < v)
            {
                v = v1;
            }
        }
        return v;
    }          
}
```

Max in this case would be Black Checkers ( Computer AI ) and Min is Red Checker, the human player

Let me briefly explain what I am trying to do with my code above. I have a TreeNode structure that stores the GameBoard, next possible move and also the Heuristic value

In My Max Move, I get all the possible Red Move Nodes from the current board. Logic for finding all possible moves is working absolutely fine. And for my Min Move which would be the human player, I get all its possible black nodes.

I am currently testing the code with depths 2 to 3 for my game tree. Please correct me if my current implementation is wrong. And finally how or where do I trace the final path of all my final Tree Nodes based on Min and Max values generated and get the next move for the Black Checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual implementation for this is to have only a MaxMove function, and negate
the value returned.

You only need to remember the top level move, although remembering the path
to the move that constitutes the principal variation can be helpful to 
understand the result, you only need to make the best move and re-run the
search from the new position after the opponent responds.

Comment: That makes sense. I understand running it every time when the human player makes the move. Just to be clear on this part, say human makes a move for the red checker. Next up the computer AI would calculate the next move using the MinMax algorithm for all the current black checkers that can make a move. In the game tree itself, the top level would always have all red checker nodes ( MIN Branch ), so then how would I get the final move for the AI from the top level? It gives me the final move for the red checker and not the black one. I am slightly confused on this part. Please correct me here.

Comment: You need to erase notions of red and black from your mind, they'll just confuse you.  Current player tries all possible moves, and returns the one with the best value.  Usually the object representing that move will contain other things, such as the value, and the best continuation move.